# TIMESTAMP_SECONDS parsing errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been trying to use the `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` function to convert some epoch timestamps in seconds format, but I have some bad data.  Is there such a thing as `SAFE_TIMESTAMP`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such a thing as SAFE_TIMESTAMP

There is! It's called `SAFE.TIMESTAMP_SECONDS`. You can apply the `SAFE.` prefix to functions to make them return `NULL` instead of an error; see [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/syntax#safe_prefix) for more reading. For example:

```
SELECT SAFE.TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

For a valid number of seconds since the epoch:

```
SELECT SAFE.TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1539973868);
+------------------------+
| f0_                    |
+------------------------+
| 2018-10-19 18:31:08+00 |
+------------------------+
```